# face_emotion() of indicoio package giving "Couldn't connect to host" error

Tags: r, image-processing, machine-learning, png, indico

First i read the image using

`img<-readPNG(imageLocation)`

imageLocation is the path of the image location with path.expand()

```
imageLocation = path.expand("~/R/funwithR/data/mero_photoforanalysis.png")
```

Converting to grayscale is done by

```
img <- 0.2126 * img[, , 1] + 0.7152 * img[, , 2] + 0.0722 * img[, , 3]
```

finally error is given by

```
face_emotion(img)
```

The error is

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is with the format you are passing to the indico API. As shown in the indico [docs](https://indico.io/docs#image-format), the API accepts the filepath as input. Not an image object.

On the plus side, there's no need for you to convert to grayscale. If you simple run the following code instead it should work:

```
fer(path.expand("~/R/funwithR/data/mero_photoforanalysis.png"))
```